# Save python data structure to import later

Tags: python

My program creates a probabilistic model that I want to save as a module to import later. How can I save it in a way that it can be directly imported?

**Json** is good for dicts, but I have different data structures, **Pickle** does not seem to allow to use `import` directly and **pprint** does not print the name and assignment of the structures.

I would just like to create some data structures:

```
states = (
    'Bound',
    'Not-bound'
)

Prob = {
    'Bound': 0.45,
    'Not-bound': 0.55
}
```

save them *somehow* to a 'py' file:

```
with open('model.py', 'wb') as out:
    save(states)
    save(Prob)
```

Then, import them later directly:

```
import model
print(model.states)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pickle.html) module.

> The pickle module implements binary protocols for serializing and de-serializing a Python object structure. “Pickling” is the process whereby a Python object hierarchy is converted into a byte stream, and “unpickling” is the inverse operation, whereby a byte stream (from a binary file or bytes-like object) is converted back into an object hierarchy.

It won't be quite the way you want it to be but I think it's a simple and reasonable way of doing what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I find pickle useful but for my purpose is not ideal. I'd want something that outputs Python code as it is writen (e.g. a = "string" instead of outputing "string") and something that is still human-readable (like Json).